# Adding in loading and error text with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was wondering how easy is to to expand this code so that it shows an error if it cannot connect and whilst it is connecting it shows a loading text or loading image. It seems pretty standard behaviour on ajax driven sites but I haven't found much useful information online on how to achieve it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var loadUrl = 'http://sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html';

    $("#close").click(function () {
        $("#country_slide").hide();
    });

    $("#country").click(function () {
        $("#country_slide").show();
        $("#country_slide").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

});
```

Comment: Everything AJAX in jQuery uses the super method `$.ajax`. Look for it on the docs, there you get success and error callbacks (and many others).

Comment: Like this? $("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"demo_test.txt",success:function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
});

Comment: Yeah, something like that plus the `error` callback should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context of your application, you can subscribe callbacks to fire on certain *global* AJAX events. Say, whenever an AJAX call starts, or whenever an AJAX call throws an error.

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function (e) {
        $('body').showMyAwesomeLoadingGIF();
    })
    .ajaxComplete(function (e) {
        $('body').hideMyAwesomeLoadingGIF();
    });
```

This will cause those two callback functions to fire during the appropriate lifecycle events *on every AJAX call made in your document*.

If, for some reason, you want a certain AJAX call **not** to trigger your global AJAX event handlers, you can specify that that particulat AJAX call is *not global*.

```
$.ajax({
    global : false,
    // blah
})
```

[More information on global AJAX event handling here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).

#### EDIT

If you want to maintain a bit more granular control, there's `$.ajaxSetup()`, but since jQuery themselves discourages its use, I'm thinking you might be left with having to fashion your own solution.

Personally, I'd use a wrapper function with a closure to set my custom option values if they're something you expect to do repeatedly.

```
var ajax = (function () {

    var defaults = { };
    return function (opts) {
        opts = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);

        // place what you want to happen when an AJAX call starts here

        return $.ajax(opts)
            // place corresponding events here
            .done(function (m) {
            })
            .fail(function (x,s,e) {
            })
            .complete(function (m) {
            });
    };

}());

// then use that in your code like how you'd use $.ajax():

ajax({
    url : 'http://my.domain.com/api/users',
    type : 'GET'
}).done(function (m) {
    console.log('Done GET users.');
});

// ... and you can be sure that it has default options and default event handlers,
//     while being able to add on to them if you wish.
```

Comment: Can this be used with my code above? How can I do it non globally, since eahc situation will be different unfortunatly

Comment: @JamesWillson ~ you can use `global : false` in your AJAX calls not to trip the global events, but if you're looking for something targeted to a smaller scope, I've edited my answer with an idea.